# Display accurate percentage

Tags: php, laravel

Hi I am trying to display the percentage 
like this:  10% but I am getting 10.526315789474%

How I can convert this into only 10%

My Code is:

```
$allUser = \Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::table('users')
        ->leftjoin('member_type','users.memberTypeID','=','member_type.id')
        ->where('member_type.name','=','Client')->count();

$memberShip = \Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::table('users')
        ->leftjoin('member_type','users.memberTypeID','=','member_type.id')
        ->where('member_type.name','=','Client')
        ->where('users.isActive','=','Y')->count();

$activeUser = ($memberShip/$allUser) * 100;
```

Comment: You could use round() I guess

Answer (score 1):

Depends on exactly what you want to do:

```
$activeUser = (int)(sprintf('%d',  ($memberShip/$allUser) * 100));  // To round off
$activeUser = round( ($memberShip/$allUser) * 100);  // To round up
$activeUser = floor( ($memberShip/$allUser) * 100);  // To round down
```

Answer (score -1):

[Round](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.round.php) is probably what you are looking for

```
$activeUser = round(($memberShip/$allUser) * 100);
```

In laravel you can do it as Blade too which will be something like `{{round($activeUser)}}%`.

Comment: Ok Thats good ... here i am facing another problem i need to display the current gym members thorugh graph means if there is 4 members the graph line should be with lenth 4 and if member is 10 the graph length should be like length 10 .....

Comment: my graph code is :         <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 member-ship">
                                <div class="over-current-gym">
                                    <p>Current gym membership</p>
                                    <h3>{{$memberShip}}</h3>
                                    <span>members</span>
                                    <img src="{{asset('images/cn-sm-img.gif')}}">
                                </div>
                            </div>

Comment: Calling round(10.526315789474) returns 11. The OP wanted to round down.

Comment: @shahzadhussain ask an other question for this ;).

Answer (score -1):

You can convert the calculated percentage to integer and it will always round off to the lower interger number. i.e. 10.9999 will be 10 only.

Comment: we can also do this like :    $activeUser = number_format($activeUser);

Comment: In both ways 1- round and 2- number_format it worked.